# Use Read-Host to gather a Phone number

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm working on a **Powershell** script that asks for several pieces of intel and then it creates an AD User Object with the data.  One thing I'd like to add is the user's **phone number**.  Here, in the States, phone numbers are generally composed of **10 digits**.  I'd like the code to make sure nobody is adding hyphens or periods between the area code, exchange, etc. because I just want the **digits**.  I had planned on using the **format operator** to make it look good (normalize it) in the AD User Object.  I tried playing with adding `[int]` to my variable but that only gets me so far as I can't seem to specify 10 digits.

I've used `Read-Host` before to prompt a user with choices (A, B, C, etc.) so that's what I know.  If something other than one of those letters was used as an answer, it would ask the question again - until it was answered correctly.  If there's a better way to request a 10-digit number, I'll be all for learning something new.

Comment: Don't make the user jump through extra hoops. Let them type the number however they want, have code (probably a regex) to strip out anything that's not a digit, and validate what's left has a length of 10. However, **you will NOT be able to assign phone numbers to an [int] variable**. Integers have a maximum value of just a little over 2.1 billion, and phone numbers go up to  nearly 10 billion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest allowing the user to input the phone number in whatever format they want, then sanitize it after the fact:

```
# Read input
$phoneNumber = Read-Host "Input 10 digit phone number"

# Remove anything that isn't a digit
$cleanNumber = $phoneNumber -replace '[^0-9]'

# Validate
if ($cleanNumber.Length -ne 10){
    # error handling goes here, 
    # perhaps you wanna go back 
    # to the top of a containing loop
    Write-Error "Invalid phone number!"
}
else {
    $formattedNumber = '({0}) {1}-{2}' -f $cleanNumber.Substring(0,3),$cleanNumber.Substring(3,3),$cleanNumber.Substring(6)
    Write-Host "You entered the phone number: $formattedNumber"
}
```

Now the user can pick whatever formatting they want when writing the password in the prompt:

```
Input 10 digit phone number: 1234567890
You entered the phone number: (123) 456-7890
```

or

```
Input 10 digit phone number: (123) 4567890
You entered the phone number: (123) 456-7890
```

Comment: I always have a hard time following RegEx. Hoping you can explain what that's doing. In my research, I found a guy who set a variable like this `$a = 5551234567` and then he formatted like this `“{0:###-###-####}” -f $a`. World of difference between the two styles. Yours works but I still found both formatting strings interesting.

Comment: @RKillcrazy As the inline comment implies, `[^0-9]` will match any character that _isn't_ a digit between 0 and 9. Since we're using the `-replace` operator, they all get replaced - in this case with nothing :)

Comment: Does the caret in the RegEx string `[^0-9]` equate to the bang symbol `!` in PS?

Comment: I wouldn't try to compare regex with procedural languages, but `^` _inverts_ the expressions inside the `[...]` class so they're symmetrically opposite. `[0-9]` describes "one of any digit 0-9" whereas `[^0-9]` describes "one of the opposite of any digit 0-9"